# Wonky CSS on mod message page

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, design

I went to send a suspend notice to someone this morning using Firefox and was greeted with this mess:

[image: gah! I can't type in that!]

It worked just fine in Chrome, I am not sure about IE at this time.

Comment: muuhaha, sneak peek at the mod tools! *evil cackle*

Comment: Looks right for me in Firefox 10.0.1; not sure if it's Christianity-specific, but I would assume not if Shog migrated it here

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I'm running 11.0

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: It was confirmed on another 2.0 site too...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Safari 5.1.5, with _Drupal Answers_, but I can reproduce it on Firefox 12, for the same site. I guess it's not specific for a site. Would adding a screenshot for _Drupal Answers_ help?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have repro on Gardening so I assume its a FF 11/12 problem not a site specific one.

Comment: Just upgraded to 11.0 (Linux); still don't see it, but I guess it doesn't really matter

Comment: Works fine in IE 9, both in compat mode and non-compat.  Which makes me laugh heartily.  FF has been having *so many problems lately*.  The last four or five rendering bugs I've seen here were all FF.  Found one in Chrome where the reputation graph failed at anything other than 100% zoom.  Haven't found any in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to our designer, the floating is needed (because he is a lazy designer :)  However, the mod page was using jquery to alter the display, which was the root cause.

This will be fixed in the next build, > rev 2012.10.18.4480.

Comment: You're saying more jQuery wasn't the solution? That it was, in fact, a problem? **Shun the heretic.**

Comment: Well, to fix it, I had to use more jQuery :)

Comment: yeah, it works now! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Reproduced in FF 12 after another moderator observed it in FF 11. Looks like the issue here is:

```
.wmd-button-bar
{
   ...
   float:left;
}
```

Not sure why that needs to float, but Firefox doesn't like it. (Note that Stack Overflow doesn't exhibit this problem, and also lacks a floating button bar)