# Mod Private Message editor unusable on many sites (Firefox)

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wonky CSS on mod message page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127903/wonky-css-on-mod-message-page)

The Moderator Private Message editor became unusable on many sites. It's pushed far to the right (see clip below). It works on some sites but not others (Genealogy shown below). It works in Chrome but does not in Firefox (latest v.16.0.1).

[image]

Comment: The problem is the yellow ninja: It's him who is moving the text box to the right. `;)`

Comment: Holy sh!t cakes, you referenced [Scorpion from Mortal Kombat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorpion_(Mortal_Kombat)).  I love fighting games, sue me.

Comment: Genealogy is 9 days old and there's already someone there that needs to be mod messaged? <sigh>

Comment: @kiamlaluno Really, did you just call him the "yellow ninja"?!?!?  You need to read up!

Comment: @YannisRizos He's testing it on himself, see the rendered HTML under the editor.

Comment: Alright, what have you pesky community managers done this time?

Comment: @casperOne I know, right? He's clearly a goldenrod ninja.

Comment: FWIW, this one is way cooler, because it has Scorpion.

Comment: @casperOne Nah, Sub Zero is the cool one...

Comment: @YannisRizos Referring to this version of the post, not the ninjas.  Everyone knows [Smoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_(Mortal_Kombat)) is the best.

Comment: @YannisRizos I see what you did there.